# Swing Java how to make multiple buttons That do different tasks on Click

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am a studying programming we just started Swing I have to make a simple boat management I need about 20 buttons. I am using the `setVisible()` method for every button I just wonder if is there another way of doing that.

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
            {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                button.setVisible(false);
                button1.setVisible(false);


                button2.setVisible(true);
                button3.setVisible(true);
            }
       });
```

Comment: Should we answer to the question in the title, or to your wondering in the question? They don't seem to have anything in common?

Comment: I mean if i press a button it will go to diffrent buttons eg. Button: Press here to add boats. and then it goes to Name of boats adding them to your list etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you could define two utility methods like

```
static void setVisible(JButton... btns) {
    for (JButton btn : btns) {
        btn.setVisible(true);
    }
}
static void setInvisible(JButton... btns) {
    for (JButton btn : btns) {
        btn.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Then you could call those with any number of buttons; like

```
setInvisible(button, button1);
setVisible(button2, button3);
```

As for making different buttons do different things, define an `ActionListener` per button (or per unique action).

Answer (score 0):

Just add another new ActionListener(){....} to each button and modify the actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) method accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can just implement the action listener in your class like:

```
public class XYZ implements ActionListener
```

Then add it to your buttons like:

```
b1.addActionListener(this);
b2.addActionListener(this); 
...
```

Then override the actionPerformed method:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //Here do your tasks.
    // To identify the button, use : e.getSource();
}
```